# Should exceptions raised due to missing params be rescued?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, parameters, rescue

Should exceptions raised due to missing params be rescued?

For example, in the following code in `FriendRequestsController`:

```
def update
  @request = FriendRequest.find(params[:id])

  if @request.update(friend_request_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Friend request updated successfully."
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    flash[:errors] = @request.errors.full_messages
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end

private
  def friend_request_params
    params.require(:friend_request).permit(:status)
  end
```

If the call to update on the model fails, the error message(s) will be stored in `flash`. But if there is something wrong with `params` such that an exception is raised in the `friend_request_params` helper method, the app will fail.

Is it the convention to allow that? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short the answer is no.  When you call

```
  def friend_request_params
    params.require(:friend_request).permit(:status)
  end
```

You have established a contract with any action that uses the `friend_request_params`.  If that action calls `friend_request_params` and doesn't send a `:friend_request`, the action has violated the contract and an exception should be raised.  Your application is legitimately not working as designed and the exception is your canary in the coal mine so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

No, they shouldn't. If an exception happens with your params it is because something weird or not expected is happening. It can be a bug, or it can be someone messing with the form. If `friend_request_params` raises an exception, just show a nice webpage to your users such as public/500.html or public/400.html.

You can look at your logs to track the exceptions, or implement a catch all to log them in a more convenient way using [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I choose the other answer because I thought it was slightly better worded.